# Bootstrap Carousel at Prestashop template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, templates, carousel, prestashop-1.6

I want to use bootstrap carousel at Prestashop template.
I have found that carousel is disabled in prestashop bootstrap. Is there any way to enable carousel?
I tried to use this code:

```
          <div class="row">
          <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                  <div class="item active">
                    <img src="{$img_store_dir}{$store.id_store}.jpg" alt="Chania">
                  </div>
                  <div class="item active">
                    <img src="{$img_store_dir}{$store.id_store}.jpg" alt="Chania">
                  </div>
                </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

I even tried to put carousel.js and css formatting to global.css but with no success.

Url: https://eshop.brunnerteppi.ch/filialen

Click on "Detail" and it shows the screen with the carousel code.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off "Minify Javascript" in Prestashop's performance tab.

When it's on there is an issue with your Google Maps javascript code, which is most likely blocking your carousel code. Try opening your developer console (F12) and look in the console.